# ALMACENAR UN VALOR EN UNA VARIABLE

Tags: javascript, variables

Necesito saber como hacer para almacenar en una variable los datos introducidos por un usuario.

Estoy practicando unos ejercicios y no logro hacerlo.

> Declarar una variable precio_manzana con el valor 2
>
> Solicitar al usuario los kilos de manzanas comprados almacenando el valor en la variable `kilos_manzana`.

Lo tengo así, no se si esta bien!

```js
var precio_manzana = 2;
var kilos_manzana = prompt("Cuantos kilos de manzana compro?");
kilos_manzana = number(kilos);
```

Comment: En la linea var kilos_manzana = prompt("Cuantos kilos de manzana compro?"); ya estas almacenando la variable con  los datos del usuario. Si quieres ver lo que tiene la variable puedes poner console.log(kilos_manzana); y saldrá en consola. No se que más código tengas pero aquí kilos_manzana = number(kilos);  ¿qué es number? ¿una función? porque solo con el código que has puesto da error.

Answer (score 0):

En programación cuando tienes un signo '=' estamos hablando de una asignación, mientras que cuando tienes '==' es una comparación.
cuando solicitas al usuario el número de kilos (prompt()) ya lo estás guardando en la variable.

Answer (score 0):

La función que quieres llamar es con N, [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) y como ya te comentaron, desde la línea `var kilos_manzana = prompt("Cuantos kilos de manzana compro?");` ya estas almacenando el valor del usuario, pero con `Number` estas "comprobando" que si se trata de un numero, aquí dejo el código con la corrección y la lógica que usas.

```
var precio_manzana = 2;
var kilos_manzana = prompt("Cuantos kilos de manzana compro?");
kilos_manzana = Number(kilos_manzana);
console.log(kilos_manzana);
```